# Texmaker - user shortcut

Tags: texmaker, shortcut

In Texmaker, how can put a new tag from the Structure tab -> User (a button on the left bar). Can I put a keyboard shortcut for this, and how?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Short version: read http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION33

---

So to add a new tag to the User-panel, you right-click in the panel and choose *Add tag*:

[image: right-click menu in user panel]

You will then see this window:

[image: add tag-dialog]

It's not immediately obvious what to put in the *Keyboard trigger* field, but reading [the manual](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION33) gives a hint. You don't write a normal keyboard shortcut, you write a string, an identifier. For example, you can write `foo`:

[image: add tag-dialog with content]

To actually use this:

1. Write in your document `:foo`, i.e. ` colon followed by what you wrote in the *Keyboard trigger* field:

   [image: Texmaker window with :foo]
2. Hit the **right arrow key**, <kbd>→</kbd>. This will insert the *LaTeX content* of the tag instead of `:<tag identifier>`:

   [image: Texmaker window with text of tag, instead of :foo]

Comment: Ok!+1. I have removed my comment. Thanks a lot and good work.